# nontrivial solution with all components nonzero

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have the set of equations

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1\\ 
a & -b & -c\\
a^2 & -b^2 & -c^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=0
 $

I think that, if all $x$, $y$ and $z$ are required to be non-zero, then $a = b = c$, but I don't know how to actually show this. I tried setting the determinant equal to zero, required for a non-trivial solution, but this is not sufficient as then (e.g.) $a=b$ and $z=0$ is a non-trivial solution. Is there a way to require that the all the components of a non-trivial solution be non-zero?

What I actually want to show is that, if for all $t$,

$
A \sin(\omega_1 t) - B\sin(\omega_2 t) = C \sin(\omega_3 t)
$

implies that $\omega_1 = \omega_2 = \omega_3$ if $A$,$B$ and $C$ are non-zero (which I think is true). Evaluating the original equation and the first and second derivative gave the set of equations above.

Any insight into either problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Thank you, that gave some insight, but I still couldn't find a solution to my problem. The Vandermode matrix's determinant was given as a product of (x_i - x_j) so that if any of the 'points' are equal then the determinant is zero. I could not see how I could use it to show that all the 'points' are equal if all the coefficients are non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Note first that if $\omega_1=\omega_2$ then 
$$A \sin(\omega_1 t) - B\sin(\omega_2 t) = C \sin(\omega_3 t)$$
becomes
$$(A-B) \sin(\omega_1t)=C \sin(\omega_3 t)$$
from which is trivial (just derivate and combine the relations) to deduce that $\omega_3=\omega_1$.

Same way, if $\omega_1=\omega_3$ you get 
$$(A-C) \sin(\omega_1t)=B \sin(\omega_2 t)$$
while if $\omega_2=\omega_3$ you get 
$$A \sin(\omega_1t)=(B+C) \sin(\omega_2 t)$$

In all three situations you can conclude that, if two of them are equal all three are equal.

**This leaves** only the case when $\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3$ are pairwise distinct. In this case the vanDermonde determinant is non-zero, therefore your system only has the trivial solution.

---

**Note** To make this clear, in the first problem one of the following two must happen.

- $\det\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -1 & -1\\ 
  a & -b & -c\\
  a^2 & -b^2 & -c^2\\
  \end{bmatrix}\neq 0$. Then the matrix is invertible and, multiplying by the inverse you get, $x=y=z=0$.
- $\det\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -1 & -1\\ 
  a & -b & -c\\
  a^2 & -b^2 & -c^2\\
  \end{bmatrix}= 0$. Then, $(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)=0$. In this case, the nly thing you can deduce is that **two of you numbers must be equal**.

You need to go back to the original problem, and deduce from there that the third number must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x'=x,y'=-y,z'=-z$.Then $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{bmatrix}.$ Then the determinant of $M$ is $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$. Multiply both sides of the matrix equation on the left by the adjoint matrix of $M.$ Thus$$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$.Thus$$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)x'=0,(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)y'=0,(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)z'=0$$and so$$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)x=0,(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)y=0,(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)z=0$$ Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for thorough response. However, the last equation seems to be satisfied with (e.g.) a = b with no requirement for c. I think if we let c be non-zero, then z' has to be zero, Can we say that a=b=c if x', y', z' are all non-zero?

Comment: I guess if we assume a=b an plug into the original equation (using first two rows) and then set z not equal to 0 this implies c = a, to get a=b=c. Then this could be repeated for b=c and c=a with x' and y' non-zero to show that for any solutions of (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)x'=0 then if x', y', z' all non-zero, a=b=c. But this seems somewhat tedious and not so general. Is there a way to show it more directly?

Comment: Be careful: when $a=b=c$, the adjoint is the zero matrix, in which case you’re effectively multiplying both sides of an equation by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the minus signs from the coefficient matrix doesn’t change its determinant and turns it into a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), with determinant equal to $(a-b)(a-c)(c-b)$. The most you can say from that is that for the equation to have a nontrivial solution, at least two of the parameters must be equal, but that doesn’t get you to $a=b=c$. However, let’s examine the null space of the coefficient matrix.

Assume that $a\ne b$. Row-reducing the matrix produces $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&{b-c\over a-b}\\ 0&1&{a-c\over a-b} \\ 0&0&(a-c)(c-b)\end{bmatrix}.$$ The matrix is rank-deficient iff $a=c$ or $b=c$. We can see from the last column of the reduced matrix that in either case null vectors of the matrix must have a zero component, so $a=b$ is a necessary condition for a solution with no zero components. By symmetry, we must also have $a=c$. The null space of the coefficient matrix is then the orthogonal complement of $(1,-1,-1)^T$, which is spanned by $(1,1,0)^T$ and $(1,0,1)^T$ and clearly has elements with no zero entries, so $a=b=c$ is also sufficient.

You could instead solve the system of equations directly. If $z$ must be nonzero, then w.l.o.g. we can set $z=1$. From the first row, we then have $y=x-1$. Substituting this into the other two equations, we obtain $$(a-b)x+(b-c)=0 \\ (a^2-b^2)x+b^2-c^2=0.$$ Substituting for $b-c$ in the last equation gives $(a-b)(a-c)x=0$, so either $a=b$ or $a=c$. Setting $a=b$ reduces the other equation to $b-c=0$. On the other hand, setting $a=c$ transforms the equation into $(b-c)(1-x)=0$, but $1-x=-y\ne0$, so once again $b-c=0$.